# how to check status of checkboxes in gridview columns on click of button

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have used checkbox column in gridview. I want to check status of that checkboxes. On click of a button it should be checked that if any checkbox is checked or not. If none checkbox is checked then it should display alert message that check checkbox first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey, I found answer. It is as follows:

```
function checkBoxselectedornot()
{

       var frm=document.forms['aspnetForm'];
       var flag=false;
       for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)
       {
           if(document.forms[0].elements[i].id.indexOf('chkDownloadSelectedEvent')!=-1)
           {
                 if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked)
                 {
                      flag=true
                 }  
           }
       } 
      if (flag==true)
      {
        return true
      }else
      {
        alert('Please select at least one Event.')
        return false
      }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   protected void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid_InvoiceGarden.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                if (chkItem.Checked)
                    flag = true;
            }
            if (flag == true)
            {
                btnUpdate.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                btnUpdate.Visible = false;
            }      
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(document.getElementById('checkBoxId').checked) {
    //checked
} else {
    //not checked
}
```

edit: if you want to check all checkboxes of a form you can loop through the collection:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('formId').getElementsByTagName('input');
var isChecked = false
for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].checked) {
        isChecked = true;
    }
}

if(isChecked) {
    //at least one checkbox checked
}
```

Comment: thanx, but checkboxes are in gridview item template. so it can not be accessed as gridview is converted in table format in html.

Answer (score 2):

Server side:

> //in your button click event :
>
> bool flag = false;
>
> for( int i=0; i < gridview1.rows.count ; i++)
>
> {
> if(checkbox1.checked)
>
> ```
>  flag = true;
> ```
>
> }
>
> if(flag)
>
> {
>
> //means atleast one check box is checked
>
> }

Comment: Thanks for answer. Buty I have to do it with java script.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add some custom Javascript to your page for the client-side alert to show. Here's a method that I've written that works with a GridView called 'GridView1' (this should be the default name if you've just dragged the control onto your ASPX page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClientCheck() {
        var valid = false;
        var gv = document.getElementById("GridView1");

        for (var i = 0; i < gv.all.length; i++) {
            var node = gv.all[i];
            if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!valid) {
            alert("Invalid. Please select a checkbox to continue.");
        }

        return valid;
    }
</script>
```

You can see that it sets a variable to the `GridView` control to start with, then iterates through all the children in a `for` loop. If the child is a `checkbox` and it is `checked`, then we set the `valid` variable to true. If we get to the end of the iteration and no checked checkboxes are found, then `valid` remains false and we execute the alert.

To link this into your `GridView` on your ASPX page, first make the button column a `TemplateField` and surround the `LinkButton` with your client-side code. If you've used the designer to set up your columns, you can use the "Convert this field into a TemplateField" link in the column editor). Here's an example of the source you'll end up with:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Button Field" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span onclick="return ClientCheck();">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="IDClick" Text='<%# Eval("YourDataSourceItem") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        // ...your remaining columns...
```

Using the `TemplateField` lets us add any client-side code we like. Here we're adding a `span` and using `onclick` to call our `ClientCheck` method.

If you aren't bothered about the alert, you could achieve your aims by using a `CustomValidator` control, which executes on the server-side.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function CheckboxSelect() {

            var LIntCtr;
            var LIntSelectedCheckBoxes = 0;

            for (LIntCtr = 0; LIntCtr < document.forms[0].elements.length; LIntCtr++) {
                if ((document.forms[0].elements[LIntCtr].type == 'checkbox') && (document.forms[0].elements[LIntCtr].name.indexOf('chkID') > -1)) {
                    if (document.forms[0].elements[LIntCtr].checked == true) {
                        LIntSelectedCheckBoxes = parseInt(LIntSelectedCheckBoxes) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (parseInt(LIntSelectedCheckBoxes) == 0) {
                alert('User(s) Must Be Selected For operation !');
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```